# Resize causes jquery animate to loop

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

I have a menu system that I need to recalculate dimensions for on resize. It works fine on load, but on resize it triggers the event multiple times. Is there a way to fix this so the resize event doesn't loop through the event for each time resize was fired?

http://jsfiddle.net/picard102/YEa3z/

```
function sizing() {



            var currentHeight = $('.level_one li').outerHeight();
            var currentHeightIMG = $('.level_one li img').outerHeight();
            var math = currentHeight - currentHeightIMG;

            console.log(' C Height '+currentHeight);
            console.log(' IMG Height '+currentHeightIMG);
            console.log(' Math '+math);



            //
            //  Set Level Two Height
            //
            $('.level_two li').css({'height': currentHeight - math + 'px'});   


            //
            //  Show Menu   
            //


            $("#super_nav_action").click( function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
                    $(".heyo").animate({'height':'0px'}, 200, "linear");            

                    $('.level_one').animate({'margin-top': '0px'});



                    $('.level_one li').siblings().removeClass("selected");
                    $('.heyo').css({ 'border-bottom': '1px solid #fff' });
                    $('.level_one').removeClass("isAlsoDown");

                    $(this).removeClass("isDown");

                } else {

                    $(".heyo").animate({'height':  + currentHeight + 2 + 'px'}, 200, "linear"); 
                    $(this).addClass("isDown");


                }
                return false;
            });





            //  
            //  Show Level Two
            //
            $( ".level_one li" ).click(function() {


            var active_tab_selector = $(this).attr('data-menu');
            var actived_nav = $('.level_two');


            if ($('.level_one').hasClass("isAlsoDown") ) {

                    actived_nav.addClass('hide');
                    actived_nav.hide().animate({'opacity':  1}, 150);  


                     $('#' + active_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
                     $('#' + active_tab_selector).show().animate({'opacity':  1}, 150);  





                } else {

                $('.level_one').addClass("isAlsoDown");
                actived_nav.addClass('hide');
                actived_nav.hide().animate({'opacity':  0}, 1);  
                $('#' + active_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
                $('#' + active_tab_selector).show().animate({'opacity':  1}, 1);  

                }



            $('.heyo').css({ 'border-bottom': '1px solid #bababa' }); 






            $('.level_one').animate({
            position: 'relative',
            'margin-top': '-' + currentHeightIMG + 'px'
                 }, {
                duration: 300,
                complete: function() { }
                });

                $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected",  10000, "easeOutBounce");

               });



}


  $(window).load(sizing);
  $(window).resize(sizing);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the click-event-functions outside of the `sizing()` function. You will need to move your var definitions outside of that function too.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YEa3z/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question and if this will help you
But if you don't want after the resize event the list is open and close several times
 you have to separate the resize from click on li list elements
in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/S3X6Y/) this problem has been corrected.

```
  function sizing() {
        var currentHeight = $('.level_one li').outerHeight();
        var currentHeightIMG = $('.level_one li img').outerHeight();
        var math = currentHeight - currentHeightIMG;
        $('.level_two li').css({'height': currentHeight - math + 'px' });
        $('.heyo').css({'border-bottom': '1px solid #bababa'});
        $('.level_one').animate({position: 'relative','margin-top': '-' + currentHeightIMG + 'px'
        }, {duration: 300,complete: function () {}});
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected", 10000, "easeOutBounce");
    }
    $(window).on('resize',function(){
    sizing()
    })
```

and on document ready event all other code

```
$(coument).ready(function(){
  //click elements.......
})
```

If this solution does not suit your needs, i apologize for making you lose time.